# How dees Customing my view through extends LinearLayout work?

Tags: android

I want to build a `Tab` View that include a `ImageView` and a `TextView`.and I write a class named `Tab` extends `LinearLayout`.

the eclipse just let me to override its constructor,and I don't know how does it work.

and my confusion in code.

```
public Tab(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    //-----is necessary?

    //removeAllViews();

    this.context = context;
    this.layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Service.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    //-----what's different?

    //View v = this.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tab, this, true);
    View v = this.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tab, null);


    //-----which one is right?

    //this.iv = new ImageView(context, attrs);
    //this.tv = new TextView(context, attrs);

    //this.iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.tab_icon);
    //this.tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tab_text);

    //-----is necessary?

    //addView(this.iv);
    //addView(this.tv);
}
```

Comment: have no idea what is your confusion...

Comment: @pskink ummm...For example Fragment, Fragment can return a `View`, because of it have a method `onCreateView` return a `View`, but extends LinearLayout, and just use it on xml file like `<com.test.Tab/>`, I don't know how the system work, let this tag can return a `View`.

Comment: its simple: Tab -> LinearLatout -> ViewGroup -> View, so Tab is a View too

Comment: @pskink Ummmm....I need to study more.